# How to handle file uploads in a webpage

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to write a .php to handle file upload on a website. I have tried numerous times but the file just would not be uploaded to the directory.

At first, I thought it might be a permission problem, but I have changed the mode to drwx-rwx-rwx, which should mean that the everyone has this directory's permission.

I even tried out the example on the tutorial site (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_file_uploading.htm) but still no result.

When executing, the program does respond to non-jpeg/png files by showing the output message "Array ( [0] => extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file. )". And when a png file is sent, it shows "success" but has file size 0, whereas on the tutorial site, the stimulation gives out the correct file size output.

My directory tree is:

```
/project --
    FileUpload.php
    /images
```

Does anyone have any idea what the problem is?

```
<?php
   if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
      $errors= array();
      $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
      $file_size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
      $file_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
      $file_type = $_FILES['image']['type'];
      $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['image']['name'])));

      $expensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png");

      if(in_array($file_ext,$expensions)=== false){
         $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file.";
      }

      if($file_size > 2097152) {
         $errors[]='File size must be excately 2 MB';
      }

      if(empty($errors)==true) {
         move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"images/".$file_name);
         echo "Success";
      }else{
         print_r($errors);
      }
   }
?>
<html>
   <body>

      <form action = "" method = "POST" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
         <input type = "file" name = "image" />
         <input type = "submit"/>

         <ul>
            <li>Sent file: <?php echo $_FILES['image']['name'];  ?>
            <li>File size: <?php echo $_FILES['image']['size'];  ?>
            <li>File type: <?php echo $_FILES['image']['type'] ?>
         </ul>

      </form>

   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tested your script and it works fine. You are checking for the uploaded file in the `images/` dir below the directory the above script is in, right?

Comment: I have included the dir tree in the question.

Comment: Looks good. Perhaps `move_uploaded_file` returns false? It should emit a notice, if so. You can enable these for the script by adding `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to the top of the script.

Comment: I've added that, but did not get any notices and the png file is still not uploaded successfully. Could this be a problem of the web hosting server maybe?

Comment: I checked and move_uploaded_file returns true.

Comment: What does `realpath( 'images/' )` output, and are you sure you checked there?

Answer (score 0):

Tested  your code, the code is fine. But the problem is while uploading the file with size more then that is defined in your `php.ini` file, it will not so anything and will not upload the file.

I tested your code  by uploading file having size less then the size defined in my `php.ini` file(i had 2M defined), it uploads successfully. Then i try to upload the file having file size more then `2M` but neither it shows error not it upload the file .

So, I just change the `upload_max_filesize`  to `8M` and try to upload then it works also gives error if the file size is less then `2M`.

Comment: My file size in php.ini is 2M as well. But I have uploaded file that is less than  2M and it still isn't uploaded successfully.

Comment: which os are you using ? If you are using linux then check the folder permission it should be 777.

Comment: It's: Access: (0777/drwxrwxrwx)

Comment: what should the permission of the .php file be set to? should it be 777 (rwx or r-x or r--)

Comment: it should be 0644 or 0755. but the folder permission should be 0777.

Comment: They are set accordingly but still no luck..... Just to make sure that the server does not have a problem, I have no issue using a FTPClient (FileZilla) to upload files.  What is really weird is that move_uploaded_file returns true... but the file is no where to be seen.

Comment: what size of file you are uploading ?